# Formula of Oxone

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, identification

A problem in my book asked the commercial name of sodium peroxide. The answer given was '**Oxone**'. Even the website https://www.911metallurgist.com/oxone/ mentions oxone as sodium peroxide.

However, upon searching '**Oxone**' on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_peroxymonosulfate), gives another compound named potassium peroxymonosulfate.

So what exactly is **Oxone**?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: I believe if you search darknet for `oxone`, you are also going to find some new funky chemicals with the same name. Don't take everything posted on the internet for granted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [1, p. 828] (and many other organic chemistry textbooks), Oxone's formula is equally written as $\ce{KHSO5 * 0.5KHSO4 * 0.5K2SO4}$ or $\ce{2KHSO5 * KHSO4 * K2SO4}$, a potassium monopersulfate triple salt:

> **Oxone®**
>   $(\ce{2KHSO5 * KHSO4 * K2SO4})$
>
> A “triple salt”, providing a convenient source of potassium monoperoxysulfate (potassium hydrogen persulfate)
>   [37222-66-51]
>
> **Commercially available**
>
> **Notes:** This reagent is a useful oxidizing agent.
>
> [image]

[Sodium peroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_peroxide) is not mentioned as *Oxone* in any of the respectable literature sources I flipped through; rather, its names would be *Solozone* and *Flocool*.

#### References

1. Mundy, B. P.; Ellerd, M. G.; Favaloro, F. G. Name Reactions and Reagents in Organic Synthesis, 2nd ed.; *Wiley: Hoboken, N.J.*; **2005**.